# CSS <td> position fixed shrinks/moves element

Tags: css, gwt, repository

Im using GWT. I need to make two columns fixed, to freeze them, and the others should scroll fluently. 
Here is simple layout before freezing two first columns (where numbers are indicated and Z column)

[image]

After freezing:

[image]

As you can see, if freezes correctly I can scroll and two first columns dont move. HOWEVER, A column content goes before Z column and disappears. (I moved Z column to show how A column content hides *purple color*)

My css:

```
//for number column
tr.Row td.row1 {
  border-color: #ffffff;
  position : fixed;
  height : 119px;
  left : 344px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
// for Z COLUMN
.lockHead{
    position: fixed;
    z-index:1!important;
}
```

Maybe a solution is to use `padding-left` or smt? Please help Im totaly stuck on it.

Comment: Please provide some code (not CSS only). I don't understand your two excel images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give the GWT table a class like `class="fixed_header"` and style the rest via CSS. Your CSS approach seem a little bit complicated I think.

Can you check if this is what you want to achive? A fixed header. CSS:

```
.fixed_header {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.fixed_header td:nth-child(1), th:nth-child(1){
  min-width: 100px;
}

.fixed_header thead tr {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.fixed_header tbody {
  height: 60px;
  display: block; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghsroh81/